# AngularJS using value service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

have an understanding problem with .value() and the use of it in controllers...
In the following example, declare the .value() in services.js :

```
.value("ScanDatas",{
    scanData: {}
})
```

Think once defined "scanData" is available in the whole app... use it in a factory :

```
.factory("ScanService", ["ScanDatas","$cordovaBarcodeScanner", function (ScanDatas,$cordovaBarcodeScanner) {
var scan = {};

scan.scanBarCode = function(){
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(datas){
        scanData.collectedDatas.text = datas.text;
        scanData.collectedDatas.format = datas.format;
        scanData.collectedDatas.cancelled = datas.cancelled;
    },function(error){
        scanData.collectedDatas.error = error;
    })
}

scan.getBarcodeData = function(){
    return scanData;
};

return scan;
}])
```

Then want to use result in a controller :

```
    .controller("ajouterCtrl", ["$scope", "$ionicPopup", "$timeout", "ScanDatas", "ScanService" , "storageAreaService", function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, ScanDatas, ScanService, storageAreaService) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.storageAreas = storageAreaService.storageAreaList();
    $scope.add = {}; // Initalise l'objet

    var barcodeData = {}; // Données lues à partir du lecteur de code barre

    $scope.scanBarCode = function(){
        ScanService.scanBarCode();
    };

    //barcodeData = ScanService.getBarcodeData();
    $scope.add.ean = scanData.collectedDatas.text;


}])
```

Finally, debug returns that scanData, or collectedDatas (don't really know what) is undefined...

Any idea or suggestion ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScanDatas` value is an object with a `scanData` field. In your service and controller you have it injected as `ScanDatas` but you are not referencing it anywhere?

Try for instance:

```
scan.getBarcodeData = function(){
    return ScanDatas.scanData;
};
```

Comment: Thx... Learning AngularJS is not as easy as i could think... Now, explore promise and other to complete my app... Maybe have a new question on how to defer my scan method to populate field in the view

Answer (score 0):

You must reference used value recipe by it's defined name:

```
scan.scanBarCode = function(){
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(datas){
        // You must also initialize the object that references collectedData before using it
        ScanDatas.scanData.collectedDatas = {};
        ScanDatas.scanData.collectedDatas.text = datas.text;
        ScanDatas.scanData.collectedDatas.format = datas.format;
        ScanDatas.scanData.collectedDatas.cancelled = datas.cancelled;

}
```

So, you had two errors there. One with the incorect reference of value recipe by scanData instead of `ScanDatas.scanData` and the other with `colectedData` being undefined if not initialized with empty object.

Also here you have a bad reference as @Joppe showed in his answer:

```
scan.getBarcodeData = function(){
    // return scanData; nope
    return ScanDatas.scanData; // sure
};
```